# undefined reference в `pthread_create' на Linux при использовании g++ qt

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, g++

Пытаюсь создать stream в c ++ с использованием g++ компилятора и qt.

Получаю ошибку:

> undefined reference to `pthread_create'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyClass{
public:
    void a(){
        std::cout << "sdsadsa" << std::endl;
    }
    void b(){
        std::cout << "dadsa" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    MyClass c;
    std::thread th([&](){
        c.a();
        c.b();
    });
    th.detach();
    int a = 5 + 6;
    std::cout << a  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Реализация `<thread>` в GCC базируется на библиотеке pthreads. Библиотека pthreads по ряду причин никогда не подключается автоматически. Эту библиотеку при компиляции нужно не забывать подключать вручную. Это делается специальным ключом `-pthread`.

Comment: ИМХО ключ - плохое название для флага компилятора, опция еще как-то, ключ.... а значение где?

Comment: Шикарный ответ! Кратко и понятно.